# Eloquent first() and loops

Tags: php, eloquent

I'm new to Eloquent and I'm having trouble when using it with loops.

Imagine I have a table in my db called ‘Jobs’ with:

- Id – 1; value: engineer
- Id – 2 ; value: doctor
- Id – 3 ; value: nurse

I'd also have a JobTranslations table with each job translations. Then, I have this piece of code:

```
     $jobTranslations = [];

        $lang = $request->input('lang') ?? 'pt';
        foreach(Job::all() as $job) {
            $job = $job->with(['jobtranslations' => function($query) use ($lang) {
                $query->where('languageCode', $lang);
            }])->firstOrFail();
          $jobTranslations[] = $job;
}        
        return ['translatedJobs' => $jobTranslations];
```

When I run this code, I’m expecting to get an array (jobTranslations) with those 3 jobs in it and each job’s translation.
However, I get instead an array with three items, but they’re all the same:

```
array([‘id’ => 1, ‘value’ => ‘engineer’, ‘jobtranslations’ => [another array]],
      [‘id’ => 1, ‘value’ => ‘engineer’, ‘jobtranslations’ => [another array]], 
      [‘id’ => 1, ‘value’ => ‘engineer’, ‘jobtranslations’ => [another array]]
);
```

I’ve realized this is happening due to ‘firstOrFail’ but I don’t understand why. $job->firstOrFail() doesn’t make sense to me because it’s only one job (the current one in the loop) but I don’t want to use get() either.

In C#, using EF, I’d do something like this (no need to call get or first):

```
foreach(var job in jobs) {
translatedJobs.Add(job.Include(j => j.jobtranslations.FirstOrDefault(jt => jt.languageCode == lang)));
}

return translatedJobs;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use $query->toSql() and see what is the query that is actually running and this will help you debug the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assum what you ar looking for ist this:

```
$lang = $request->input('lang', 'pt');

$jobTranslations = Job::with([
    'jobtranslations' => function ($query) use($lang)
    {
        $query->where('languageCode', $lang);
    }
])->get()->toArray();

return ['translatedJobs' => $jobTranslations];
```

There is no need to do a Foreach Loop if you setup your Model correct.